# Bring up input form on same page with dropdownlist?

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio

I'm brand new at this, using vs2010 with asp.net and c#, and I'm trying to use a button click event to display forms on my "Add Product" page (the forms will be textbox/label based for inputting data), using items from a dropdownlist of products. Which methods are available/is there a 'best practice' for this sort of thing? I've been fooling around with an if (Dropdownlist.SelectedIndexChanged) statement, but I'm not quite clear on why the syntax requires the SelectedIndexChanged method to preclude a += or -=. Thoughts?

Comment: While you are still 'brand new' at this, I would encourage you to step back and look at the MVC project template with VS 2010 and embrace that style of development rather than pursuing the 'web forms' model. If you drink the kool-aid now, it will go down easier. As you go through the tutoials available for MVC the answer to this and other questions will unfold for you...

Comment: Ahaha, quick somebody pour me a glass. I want to join this club so I can wear the funny hats! Seriously, though, I have heard that MVC template is preferable, but unfortunately I am learning on the fly with a practice project handed to me by my handler, and it's near to completion, so it'd probably be best not to switch horses mid-stream, so to speak. But thank you for the tip.

Comment: Fair enough, I wanted to fit you for the funny had before you knew it. If you are already in the swamp, best you work with what you have.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The SelectedIndexChanged method has the += because you are adding an event handler to a specific elements event.  Is the button you click on the Add Product page?  If so for the OnClick event you could just set your form details based on the DropDownList SelectedItem or SelectedIndex.  You may also need to wrap that panel in an UpdatePanel so that it can update visibility without reloading the whole page.

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="updateFormPanel" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional">
<ContentTemplate>

<asp:Label ID="lblName" runat="server" Text="" />
<asp:TextBox ID="txtDetails" runat="server" Text="" />
//More TextBox's or whatever you want

</ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel?
<asp:DropDownList ID="ddlProductCategory" runat="server" />
<asp:Button ID="btnAddProduct" runat="server" OnClick="AddProduct_Click" Text="Add Product" />

//Code File Behind
protected void AddProduct_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    lblName.Text = ddlProductCategory.SelectedItem.Text;
    txtDetails.Text = ddlProductCategory.SelectedItem.Value;
}
```